# Java Generics problems

Tags: java, generics, integer

I have this class Entry...

```
public class Entry <K, V> {
    private final K mKey;
    private final V mValue;

    public Entry() {  
        mKey = null;
        mValue = null;   
    }
}
```

What happens if I use an int as the mKey? As far as I know ints can't be null!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable of type `Integer` can be null.  An `int` cannot be null.  The latter is the primitive type, the former is a wrapper reference type for dealing with primitives as an Object.  If you're using this:

```
Entry<Integer, String> myEntry;
```

Then you are necessarily using the wrapper type.  Primitives can't be used as type parameters in Java so you can't have `Entry<int, String>` for example (it won't compile).

Comment: @Halluc: Ah, ok then well just look at the very end of my answer.

Comment: Then, can I use that Integer just as if it was an int? I really never used "Integer" except for calling it's methods (parseInt etc...)

Comment: @Halluc: Due to the wonders of [autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), you can usually interchange between `int` and `Integer` without any effort.  However, the one time you have to be careful is when assigning an `Integer` to an `int`.  The value can be null, and if it is you'll get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use primitives as type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Generic type parameters need to be objects, they can't be primitives. So you can use the `Integer` wrapper class around mKey / mValue and set it to null, but trying to use the int primitive will always give you a compilation error.